# unix convert long to wide

Tags: shell, unix, join

I know how to do this in R, but unfortunately my dataset is too big so I am trying to use the shell to transform a dataset from a long format to wide format.

the current format is something like this:

```
Name1 A 3
Name2 A 6
Name3 A 10
Name3 B 2
Name4 A 4
Name5 B 1
```

I would like to transform it to a wide format so that the second column becomes new columns and the third column becomes counts.  If there is no vale, I want to insert a 0 in its place like this:

```
Name A B
Name1 3 0
Name2 6 0
Name3 10 2
Name4 4 0
Name5 0 1
```

From my limited knowledge of linux and my online searches I really do not know how to approach this.

One thing I tried to get around this issue is to subset the file into two separate files using grep and then try a long join.

```
grep A file | sort -k 1 > file_A
grep B file | sort -k 1 > file_B
join  -o '0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3' -e "0" -a1 -a2 <(sort -k 1 file_A) <(sort -k 1 file_B) > output
```

this *appears* to work if I just run the join command.  However, when I try to direct the output to a file, I get the following error message:

```
join: /dev/fd/63:63: is not sorted: Name4   A 83
join: /dev/fd/62:15: is not sorted: Name5   B 3
```

All that I have read online indicates that this error appears when the files are not properly sorted, but I actually think I sort them by column 1 twice.

Any thoughts on the best way to go from a wide to a long format or how to troubleshot my attempt at making a summary table would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a tool for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) than `join`. You want to have a 2-dimensional data structure to hold the info. I'm using GNU awk to iterate over the array keys in sorted order.

```
gawk '
    {val[$1][$2] = $3} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        print "NAME A B"
        for (name in val) 
            print name, 0+val[name]["A"], 0+val[name]["B"]
    }
' file
```

I'm adding the value to zero so that unset array elements are treated like the  number zero instead of the empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have never used gawk before, but this script works perfectly!  Using join was my hail mary attempt to try to think creatively using commands that I felt comfortable with, but this gawk solution is much, much better!